# Should I use a single relationship or two relationships in this case?

Tags: neo4j

A relationship involving a case of, say, "friends" on a social networking platform would usually be modeled as:

```
(x:User)-[:FRIEND]->(y:User)
```

Which is then retrieved as:

```
MATCH (x:User)-[:FRIEND]-(y:User) RETURN x, y
```

Now, let's say, for a certain `x` and `y`: although they are friends with each other, `y` doesn't really trust `x`; `x` doesn't feel that way about `y` though.

So, from the perspective of `y`, the data model actually is:

```
(y)-[:FRIEND {untrusted: true}]->(x)
```

However, from the perspective of `x`, that's not how things look like:

```
(x)-[:FRIEND]->(y)
```

Thus, something like this would be clearly inappropriate for creating the relationship:

```
MATCH (x:User {...}), (y:User {...}) MERGE (x)-[f:FRIEND]->(y) SET f.untrusted = true
```

... because now, things end up looking like this from the perspective of both the users:

```
(x:User {...})-[:FRIEND {untrusted: true}]->(y:User)
(x:User {...})<-[:FRIEND {untrusted: true}]-(y:User)
```

The general advice is to usually prevent two discrete relationships in most cases, however, how should I go about modelling this case of a relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationships in Neo4j are always directed, but as you show you don't necessarily need to specify a direction when querying.

I think in this case it is helpful to compare to a Twitter-type model where users "follow" other users. That follow is not necessarily reciprocated:

```
(Will)-[:FOLLOWS]->(BarackObama)
```

does not imply that Barack Obama follows Will back.

I think this is more consistent with your data model and in this case there is nothing wrong with creating relationships in both directions.